# why route of backbone needs the default route

Tags: backbone.js, router

I create a test case with backbone.js @:
 http://jsfiddle.net/VWBvs/5/

Route is defined as

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "/posts/:id" : "getPost",
            "/download/*path": "downloadFile",  
            "*actions" : "defaultRoute"
        },
        getPost: function(id) {
            alert(id);
        },
        defaultRoute : function(actions){
            alert(actions);
        },
        downloadFile: function( path ){ 
            alert(path); // user/images/hey.gif 
        },
        loadView: function( route, action ){ 
            alert(route + "_" + action); // dashboard_graph 
        }
    });

    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    Backbone.history.start();​
```

When I change the function

```
  defaultRoute : function(actions){
            alert(actions);
        },
```

to

```
defaultRoute : function(actions){
            var action = actions
        },
```

all other routes won't work which means no dialog pops up.

But when rechange the code ,all is ok.

It's really weird and make me confused.
SOS sincerely ......

Answer (score 4):

As you have the code `defaultRoute` is the only route that ever fires. If you want the other two routes to fire you have to remove the leading slashes.

```
routes: {
  "posts/:id" : "getPost",
  "download/*path": "downloadFile",  
  "*actions" : "defaultRoute"
}
```