# Route collision between Marionette Apps. Possible ideas/solutions?

Tags: backbone.js, routes, marionette, backbone-routing

I am in the middle of building a Marionette application and just got
bit by a route collision. Being fairly new to Backbone, I am unsure of
whether or not it is possible to create a {black,white}list for
Marionette's `AppRouter`. The best leads I have seen so far are:

- Implement a [Default route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184796/why-route-of-backbone-needs-the-default-route).

  - I don't believe this will solve my problem because these Apps are in two separate modules.
- Integrate [regex-based routing](http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2011/12/regex-routing-with-backbone-js/) as an extension to `Marionette.AppRouter`.

  - This does not strike me as the simplest thing that could possibly work.

Before I layout what is happening, here is some context:

users_app.js.coffee:

```
@Gdit.module "UsersApp", (UsersApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class UsersApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      'users/:id/edit': 'editUser'
      'users/:id': 'showUser'

  API =
    showUser: (id) ->
      new UsersApp.Show.Controller
        id: id

    editUser: (id) ->
      new UsersApp.Edit.Controller
        id: id

  App.addInitializer ->
    new UsersApp.Router
      controller: API
```

roles_app.js.coffee:

```
@Gdit.module "RolesApp", (RolesApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class RolesApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      'users/roles': 'editUsersRoles'

  API =
    editUsersRoles: ->
      new RolesApp.Edit.Controller

  App.addInitializer ->
    new RolesApp.Router
      controller: API
```

The problem arises when I try to access the `Roles.Edit.Controller` through `/#users/roles`:

```
Started GET "/users/roles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-16 14:02:01 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"roles"}
```

As you can see, "roles" is being captured by the `/users/:id` route and being processed as an `id`. Not what I expected :)

Lastly, since I mentioned the "simplest thing that could possibly" work, I acknowledge that that would, in fact, be to just change the route for `editUsersRoles` to `/users_roles`. However I am more curious to see if a more elegant solution exists and see some spikes, etc. for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, Backbone stops at the first route pattern that matches a URL. So if you run `addInitializer()` for your Roles router first, it will get first crack at matching the URL.

That said, setup of that Roles router seems likely to cause maintenance problems (or at least confusion). It would be more natural to have the Roles router match on `/roles`, `/roles/:userId`, etc (or even `/users_roles` as you mentioned).

Comment: Your maintenance concern is a good one, but what confusion do you see this approach creating for someone who is used to seeing idiomatic Marionette code?

Comment: I was thinking about this sort of issue cropping up a couple years later after the codebase had expanded. Someone coming in for the first time (or just the first time in a while) might be thrown a little by this sort of route conflict. Not because it's especially complex, but because it seems to dodge convention without a good reason. My point was that eliminating surprises can be a good thing :).